# Angular2 bootstrap from AppComponent or AppModule

Tags: angular, angular-standalone-components

I'm newbie with Angular2. Please help me a little.

My root component (AppComponent) has got many link, and I use the RouterModule:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,  
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  imports: [RouterModule],
  template: `
  <main>
    <div id='header_menu'>
        <div [routerLink]="['/list1']">Link1</div>
        <div [routerLink]="['/list2']">Link2</div>                       
    </div>
  </main>
`,
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'title'; 
}
```

If I want to bootstrap on a component in app.module.ts, I must use a not standalone component else I have got error NG6009.
But if I remove standalone flag from AppComponent, I can't use imports (error NG2010).What can I do? thanks.

Comment: If you want to fully go standalone you bootstrap the AppComponent and provide the router via `provideRouter`. See [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-5juzcz?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: You're welcome. The new angular docs angular.dev are much more friendly, recommend going through them